Horizontal card slider with react
I want to implement a horizontal slider where only the centered/selected card is highlighted and others are faded out.
Example:

I tried the react-slick library. I was able to create the slider, but couldn't figure out how to implement the fading effect.

You can achieve a centered carousel layout using the centerMode property in the react-slick library. This feature allows you to center the active slide while displaying partial slides on the sides.
You can find detailed documentation and examples on how to use centerMode in the official documentation of react-slick library:
react-slick - Center Mode Example
